# "Quote" replacement on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, typographical-error

I’ve just met smart quotes `“ ”` in the place of “programmer quotes” `" "` ([Quotation Mark U+0022](https://unicode-table.com/en/0022/) officially) in [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732122/why-is-literal-encouraged-to-decay-to-const-char-in-c-argument-type-mat)’s title here on Stack Overflow:

> Why is `“literal”` encouraged to decay to `const char*` in C++ argument type match?

Since the question is speaking about a character string `"literal"`, the programmer quotes should be used IMHO. However, when I hit the Edit link, they get presented as programmer quotes:

> Why is `"literal"` encouraged to decay to `const char*` in C++ argument type match?

Firefox and Internet Explorer 11 behave the same way, so it does not look like a browser feature. Does it mean Stack Overflow gets an automatic quote replacement? While it may be OK for most Stack Exchange sites, it may harm the code samples presented in the title here on Stack Overflow.

(I used smart quotes manually in the first sentence of my question, and the replacement seems not to kick in the question body. However, I used programmer quotes in the title to illustrate it.)

Comment: Yes, but only in the question title.

Comment: Meta dupe: [Question titles collapse "-​- " (double minus signs) to "-- " (mdash)](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/193572)